# Toggle Play/Stop for plyr.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, plyr, plyr.js

I am having trouble getting my custom play/stop toggle button to work, my sceneario:
I am loading a youtube video via plyr.js. This video is hidden.
I have a custom play/stop button which sits outside the video and it is visible on the page.
I am trying to make the play/stop button to toggle the video to show/hide.
The video need to be loaded at the time of toggle to show happens.
The video need to stop at the time of toggle to hide happens.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
playVideo = function(id){
    $('#section-'+id).toggleClass('show-clue');

    if($('#section-'+id).hasClass('show-clue')){
      const video = new Plyr('#section-'+id+' .video', { controls: [
          'play-large',
          'fullscreen'
      ]});
      video.play();
    }else{
      const video = new Plyr('#section-'+id+' .video', { controls: [
          'play-large',
          'fullscreen'
      ]});
      video.stop();
    }
  }
```

The function is getting called within an onclick even like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="playVideo('2');">Clue</a>
```

My code above is giving me this error: `TypeError: this.media is undefined`

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Kindly Share fiddle.

Comment: I dont know how!

Comment: Navigate to: https://jsfiddle.net/ Add your JS, HTML, CSS then Save and comment the URL here.